# How to order years by month?

Tags: r

Assuming:

```
     s1=seq(as.Date("1950/01/01"), by = "month", length.out = 200)
```

Will give:

```
     1950-01-01
     1950-02-01
     1950-03-01
     1950-04-01
```

this is one comuln in a dataframe, I would like to arragne the whole datafram:

```
   1950-01-01
   1951-01-01
   1952-01-01
   1953-01-01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s1[order(lubridate::month(s1))]
```

or to order by month and by year

```
s1[order(lubridate::month(s1), lubridate::year(s1))]
```

in a data.frame

```
df[order(lubridate::month(df$s1), lubridate::year(df$s1)), ]
```

Comment: Say df contains s1 as a column df[order(lubridate::month(df$s1)),]

Comment: edited in df-solution